# 'str' object has no attribute 'strategy' - django-oscar

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am having trouble with this bug in django-oscar.

I have read that promotion_tags.py was not rendering the request inside context. But I have seen the oscar code inside my virtualenv, it has the request inside the context

but the weird thing is, functions inside promotion_tags.py are not being called, thus no request object in the context. but I am not sure, if this is the only place where request object is altered/added to context.

here is the code which needs the request object:

```
@register.simple_tag
def purchase_info_for_product(request, product):
    if product.is_parent:
        return request.strategy.fetch_for_parent(product)
    return request.strategy.fetch_for_product(product)
```

I am using django-oscar 1-6 and django 1.11.

here is the full traceback:

```
2018-08-17 12:52:53,567 django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /category/beauty-wellness_9/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 84, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 708, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 849, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 86, in super
    return mark_safe(self.render(self.context))
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 322, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 216, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 245, in render
    return t.render(new_context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 216, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/goldmarie/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 203, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/goldmarie/goldmarie/templatetags/gm_purchase_info_tags.py", line 13, in purchase_info_for_product
    return request.strategy.fetch_for_product(product)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strategy'
```

this is where exception is happening

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Suggest you provide enough information for someone to reproduce the problem, as it's not clear how to do so currently.

Comment: It should still be possible to provide simple steps to reproduce using the [sandbox](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/internals/sandbox.html#run-the-sandbox-locally). Without that I can't see how to help.

Comment: @solarissmoke I see that it is fixed here https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/pull/2243 but i have the newer version even and bug still comes up.. it can be that some local app customized this and has the old code?

Comment: @solarissmoke somehow, request object is empty and it is just '' (empty string). I am not so familiar with oscar, but it seems request object is altered somewhere and set to empty string.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this in vanilla Oscar, and strongly suspect that the issue arises from code in your project. Please post a full stack trace for the error, and the code of any custom templates that use the promotion_tags.

Comment: @solarissmoke ok let me do it quickly

Comment: @solarissmoke just pasted the full traceback. and I think, promotion_tag is not the problem, because I made print inside it and it is not being printed, so it is not being used in this case..

Comment: The error is coming from a file called `gm_purchase_info_tags.py` which is not part of Oscar. What is in that file?

Comment: @solarissmoke it is the overwritten version of that tag. the code of that file is pasted in the question. but i tried also with the built-in version of that template tag. same error.

Comment: In which case the issue must be that whatever is calling that template tag is doing it wrong. There must be somewhere in your overridden templates that is doing `{% purchase_info_for_product %}` and passing an invalid argument for `request`.

Comment: @solarrissmoke yep, thats the case and the request object is just an empty string. the tag is being called with request as paramater but that request is empty. do you know what it can be?

Comment: @solarissmoke any idea? :/ still stuck in the issue.

Comment: I would bet that the issue is with your local code, but can't really help without seeing it...

Comment: @solarissmoke I could share my all debug infos ifnyou want in a chat room, i came closer to issue but still didnot find the place yet

Comment: it is soo weird, right before exception happens, request object is there. I just dont get it why it is being empty string afterwards

Comment: @solarissmoke I pasted the picture of debug trace also above

Comment: @solarissmoke solved finally!! one custom template tag was not returning the context but just the variable.. what a shame.. (I am being onboarded into existing project btw).. thanks again anyway for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

See here [how to pass the template context into template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def purchase_info_for_product(context, product):
    request = context['request']
    if product.is_parent:
        return request.strategy.fetch_for_parent(product)
    return request.strategy.fetch_for_product(product)
```

With your original code, you're passing `product` in as the `request` parameter.

Alternately, if the tag is built-in in Oscar, pass in the request:

`{% purchase_info_for_product request product %}`

Comment: I did this too, but it says `KeyError 'request'`, because `'request'` is just not inside the context.

Comment: I tried to overwrite and use my own templatetag, but the problem lies somewhere else. either I am missing some middleware or some middleware is not doing its job

Answer (score 0):

Pass strategy argument in your function. But as core of the problem you are making a change in Basket app and you are not inheriting strategy devised for the basket.
This is all I can tell you with what I see in your question. If you can post complete code related to your app you forked with complete error by creating a "gist". It will be quite easy to debug. :-)